# Why can we not cast from Object[] to String[], while we can from the values in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, casting

why does this run:

```
    static TreeMap<String, int[]> configs = new TreeMap<String, int[]>();

    int[] upperarms_body = {2,3,4,6};
    int[] left_arm = {1,2};
    int[] right_arm = {6,7};
    int[] right_side = {5,6,7};
    int[] head_sternum = {3,4};


    configs.put("upperarms_body", upperarms_body);
    configs.put("left_arm", left_arm);
    configs.put("right_arm", right_arm);
    configs.put("right_side", right_side);
    configs.put("head_sternum", head_sternum);



    // create a config counter
    String[] combi = new String[configs.keySet().size()];

    Set<String> s = configs.keySet();
    int g = 0;
    for(Object str : s){
        combi[g] = (String) str; 
    }
```

and this not:

```
  static TreeMap<String, int[]> configs = new TreeMap<String, int[]>();

    int[] upperarms_body = {2,3,4,6};
    int[] left_arm = {1,2};
    int[] right_arm = {6,7};
    int[] right_side = {5,6,7};
    int[] head_sternum = {3,4};

    configs.put("upperarms_body", upperarms_body);
    configs.put("left_arm", left_arm);
    configs.put("right_arm", right_arm);
    configs.put("right_side", right_side);
    configs.put("head_sternum", head_sternum);



    //get an array of thekeys which are strings
    String[] combi = (String[]) configs.keySet().toArray();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `toArray()` returns an `Object[]` *instance*, which cannot be cast to `String[]`, just like an `Object` *instance* cannot be cast to `String`:

```
// Doesn't work:
String[] strings = (String[]) new Object[0];

// Doesn't work either:
String string = (String) new Object();
```

However, because you can assign `String` to `Object`, you can also put `String` into `Object[]` (which is what probably confuses you):

```
// This works:
Object[] array = new Object[1];
array[0] = "abc";

// ... just like this works, too:
Object o = "abc";
```

The inverse wouldn't work, of course

```
String[] array = new String[1];
// Doesn't work:
array[0] = new Object();
```

When you do this (from your code):

```
Set<String> s = configs.keySet();
int g = 0;
for(Object str : s) {
    combi[g] = (String) str; 
}
```

You're not actually casting an `Object` *instance* to `String`, you're casting a `String` instance declared as an `Object` type to `String`.

The solution to your problem would be any of these:

```
String[] combi = configs.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
String[] combi = configs.keySet().toArray(new String[configs.size()]);
```

Refer to the Javadoc for more info about [`Collection.toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 3):

A `Object[]` can have any type of object added to it. A `String[]` can only contains Strings or `null`

If you could cast the way you suggest, you would be able to do.

```
Object[] objects = new Object[1];
String[] strings = (String[]) objects; // won't compile.
objects[0] = new Thread(); // put an object in the array.
strings[0] is a Thread, or a String?
```

Comment: You get the same issue with `List<String>` vs `List<Object>` except you can bypass the compilers checks with type erasure.